# How to use map to set and get value using service?

Tags: angular

I have a shared HTML

```
 <inventory-products-list *ngIf="toggle" [products]="products" (qrCode)="generateQRCode($event)" (undeleted)="undelete($event)" (deleted)="deleteProduct($event)"></inventory-products-list>
```

this I need to use in different pages.
the component will just toggle the view based on toggle property(like grid view and list view).

I want to use a service and use map methods, like getmap() , set map() (don't know exactly how to use)
instead of toggle property, I need to create some property which will keep the value of toggle.

for example, I set the value to true in view, then I redirect to any page and coming back to the current page, true should not be reset to false. it should keep the view as I selected.

if I simply use a simple variable in service, as I am using the shared HTML in different pages. if I change in one place it will change the view in other pages also. my service is

```
     import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
     import { Client } from '../../inventory/setting/client';

     @Injectable()

     export class UIService {
   public client?: Client;
   public isFullWidth?: boolean = false;
      public data?: boolean;
  constructor() {
            }
      myMap = new Map();



     public setData(key, data) {
       console.log("here");
       this.myMap.set(key, data);
                               }

        public getData(key) {
        return this.myMap.get(key);
      }

      }
```

in my component i am doing

```
  changeView() {
this.toggle = !this.toggle;
this.uiService.setData("category",this.toggle);
console.log(this.uiService.getData("category"));
}

ngOnInit(): void {
console.log("on",this.uiService.getData("category"));
this.getCategories();
}
```

but its not keeping the key value when we change the page and come back.
what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of keeping the component values in a service is good. You can store the values in a `Map` instead of a single value shared by all instances. So each view using the component will have its own key in the map and its own data. As a key, you can use either the current route or you can create some unique names for each usage.

Edit: Example
Check the [Map class doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```
class MyService {
  private componentDataMap = new Map();

  public setData(key, data) {
    this.componentDataMap.set(key, data);
  }

  public getData(key) {
    return this.componentDataMap.get(key);
  }
}
```

If you cannot use the Map class, you can use a generic object for that:

```
var objectAsMap = {};
objectAsMap[key] = values;
var data = objectAsMap[key];
```

Comment: can you provide any link.. how to use it?

Comment: I added an example code so you have a starting point for your project.

Comment: how can i set componentDataMap propery from diffrent components?

Comment: how var objectAsMap = {};
objectAsMap[key] = values;
var data = objectAsMap[key]; this code is related to the service you have written?

Comment: The code is just an example how to read and write data with a key to an object. You don't want to change the value of `componentDataMap`, just add or get data from it using the methods I wrote in the example.

Comment: how it will keep the value even if i redirect to some page?